# hybrid_expressions in SQLAlchemy with arguments

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I currently have the following `hybrid_property` and `hybrid_property.expression()` on a model I have outlined:

```py
class Body():

    @hybrid_property
    def altitude(self, LST: float, latitude: float) -> float:
        return self.get_altitude(LST, latitude)

    @altitude.expression
    def altitude(cls, LST: float, latitude: float) -> float:
        """
        Get the altitude of the star as a raw SQL expressions
        """
        ha = (LST - cls.ra) % 360

        ra = func.radians(ha)

        dec = func.radians(cls.dec)

        lat = func.radians(latitude)

        alt = func.asin(
            func.sin(dec) * func.sin(lat) + func.cos(dec) * func.cos(lat) * func.cos(ra)
        )

        return func.degrees(alt)
```

However, when I attempt to use this within a SQLAlchemy filter as:

```
query = query.filter(self.model.altitude(LST, latitude) > 0)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: altitude() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'LST' and 'latitude'
```

Even though these are both defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a [`hybrid_method`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid.hybrid_method.__init__), the `hybrid_property` doesn't support arguments.

```py
class Body():

    @hybrid_method
    def altitude(self, LST: float, latitude: float) -> float:
        return self.get_altitude(LST, latitude)

    @altitude.expression
    def altitude(self, LST: float, latitude: float) -> float:
        """
        Get the altitude of the star as a raw SQL expressions
        """
        ha = (LST - cls.ra) % 360

        ra = func.radians(ha)

        dec = func.radians(cls.dec)

        lat = func.radians(latitude)

        alt = func.asin(
            func.sin(dec) * func.sin(lat) + func.cos(dec) * func.cos(lat) * func.cos(ra)
        )

        return func.degrees(alt)
```